# How to dynamically create check boxes or buttons in Wxpython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

```
posx = 50
for name in sheets:
    wx.CheckBox(self, -1 ,name, (15, posx))
    posx = posx + 20
```

When I execute this the check boxes appear but they dont work, meaning I cant check any of the boxes, Whats the right way to add check box or a button dynamically ?

I have now edited my code and added it to a panel, now the check boxes dont even appear

```
pnl = wx.Panel(self)
posx = 50
for name in sheets:
    cb = wx.CheckBox(pnl, label=name, pos=(20, posx))
    cb.SetValue(True)
    cb.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.doSomething)
    posx = posx + 20

def doSomething(Self,e):
sender = e.GetEventObject()
isChecked = sender.GetValue()

if isChecked:
    #do something here            
else: 
    #do something else here
```

Comment: you would have to add it to the panel or frame, then the above code would work

Comment: @BinayakaChakraborty : Please check edit, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Check scarecrow's answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works.

```
import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):

  def OnInit(self):
    frame = InsertFrame(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    return True

class InsertFrame(wx.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent, id):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Test Frame', size = (300,100))
    panel = wx.Panel(self)
    pos_y = 0
    for i in range(50):
      pos_y += 20
      cb = wx.CheckBox(panel, label="sample checkbox", pos=(20, pos_y))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = MyApp()
  app.MainLoop()
```

This just sets up the widget with the checkboxes.

Output:
[image: And the output:]

Answer (score 1):

1. Checkbox class -> http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.CheckBox-class.html
2. Button class -> http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Button-class.html
3. Example code for checkbox:

   ```
     #!/usr/bin/python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

     import wx


     class Example(wx.Frame):

     def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
     super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kw) 

     self.InitUI()

     def InitUI(self):   

      pnl = wx.Panel(self)

      cb = wx.CheckBox(pnl, label='Show title', pos=(20, 20))
      cb.SetValue(True)

      cb.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.ShowOrHideTitle)

      self.SetSize((250, 170))
      self.SetTitle('wx.CheckBox')
      self.Centre()
      self.Show(True)    

   def ShowOrHideTitle(self, e):

     sender = e.GetEventObject()
     isChecked = sender.GetValue()

     if isChecked:
       self.SetTitle('wx.CheckBox')            
     else: 
       self.SetTitle('')        

    def main():

    ex = wx.App()
     Example(None)
     ex.MainLoop()    

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
   ```
4. Example code for button:

   ```
   import wx

   class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
      """make a frame, inherits wx.Frame"""

   def __init__(self):
      # create a frame, no parent, default to wxID_ANY

    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 'wxButton',

    pos=(300, 150), size=(320, 250))
    self.SetBackgroundColour("green")
    self.button1 = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label='Button1',
    pos=(8, 8), size=(175, 28))
    self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button1Click)
     # optional tooltip
     self.button1.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip("click to hide"))

     # show the frame 
      self.Show(True)
       def button1Click(self,event):
       self.button1.Hide()
       self.SetTitle("Button1 clicked")
       self.button2.Show()

       application = wx.PySimpleApp()
       # call class MyFrame
       window = MyFrame()
       # start the event loop
       application.MainLoop()
   ```
5. A good tutorial for all other wxpython widgets: (wx.Button
        wx.ToggleButton, wx.StaticLine, wx.StaticText, wx.StaticBox
        wx.ComboBox, wx.CheckBox,wx.StatusBar,wx.RadioButton,wx.Gauge,wx.Slider and wx.SpinCtrl) 
   ->  http://zetcode.com/wxpython/widgets/